# jQuery Gallaria 1.2.3 rendering issue in Internet Explorer 8/9

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I've been working with jQuery slideshow "Gallaria". There is a rendering issue when using Internet Explorer 8/9 that looks like: [click here](http://www.johnnytrinh.com/v4-main/troubleshoot.png). I am not sure why its rendering it out so its not "fullscreen." I've tested the same page on Firefox4, Chrome and Safari and they all seem to render it as intended.

I've tried to use Firebug to find out if there are any issues on load and I have not found anything. I've reimplemented Gallaria from scratch and dug through the documentation. I can't seem to pinpoint why in Internet Explorer it behaves like this and not in the other browsers.

I have a uploaded this page to this directory: [click here](http://www.johnnytrinh.com/v4-main)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your page is in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

It looks like you've accidentally deleted this doctype line from the top of your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Add that back in (as the very first line), and it will work properly in IE.

---

You should also fix this line:

```
<html="xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

into this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

---

And this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content"text/html"; charset="utf-8"/>
```

into:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

You're also missing a closing tag for `html`; add `</html>` at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply! It is extremely appreciate it. I have made the changes and it works. Although there seems to be a weird transparent box at the top left corner. -- Edit -- Seems to disappear when you "idle" (take cursor) off page for a sec. Is there a firebug for IE that I can use to select that object?

Comment: It seems to be `<div class="galleria-iefix">` - I can't see what it's supposed to be doing - looks like some kind of transparency fix. Perhaps `.galleria-iefix { display: none }` would be a quick fix.

Comment: I found it, they just updated Galleria today and added some weird iefix opacity. Thank you again and I have accepted your answer!